# What is the probability that the sum of the numbers on the two cards is odd?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have written From $1$ to $15$ on the fifteen cards and we randomly selected two cards **Without replacement**.

What is the probability that the sum of the numbers on the two cards is odd?

Is the answer $\frac{{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 8 \\ 1 \\ \end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} 7 \\ 1 \\ \end{array}} \right)}}{{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} {15} \\ 1 \\ \end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} {14} \\ 1 \\ \end{array}} \right)}}$?

Comment: How many pairs are there with odd sum? How many pairs are there in total?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - Is this true that $\frac{{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   8  \\
   1  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   7  \\
   1  \\
\end{array}} \right)}}{{\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {15}  \\
   1  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {14}  \\
   1  \\
\end{array}} \right)}}$?

Comment: To ask a good question, you should include as much as you can of your own efforts in the question text. You can edit the question to include these details, using the link labeled "edit," as I have done to include the formula from your comment into the main question. Can you edit the question further to explain your thoughts that led you to that formula?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** to get an odd sum, you have to add an odd number and even number together. So you have to find the probability of first picking an odd number, then an even number without replacement. Also consider the other way around, where you pick an even number first then an odd number. Then you can add the two probabilities together.

Comment: @WaveX- Please more guide. Is my answer is true?

Answer (score 1):

No, your answer is not actually correct.

First of all: what is a total number of selecting $2$ cards of $15$? It is of course:
$\binom{15}{2}$. Then we need to find the combinations which suits to our situation: we have to pick $1$ of $8$ odd card, and $1$ of $7$ even card in order to get an odd sum. So the answer is:
$$\frac{\binom{8}{1}\binom{7}{1}}{\binom{15}{2}} $$

Comment: This question said for **Without replacement**. Can this answer  true?

Comment: That formula gives combinations without replacement.